# acdialog and scroll bars

Tags: ms-access, scrollbar, mode, window-resize

I have a set of Access 2013 forms that are opened as acdialog, i.e. I need to suspend execution until the form is closed. The problem is that the scroll bars and resize properties disappear. I can set Auto Resize to NO but this causes other problems.

The problem is that acdialog seems to be the only way to halt execution (of the other thread). Acdialog opens the form as a pop-up. A pop-up may exceed the window frame of the application. This works fine when the user operates the system from a large office display. However, when accessing the application from a PC using remote desktop, only a part of the pop-up window is seen. If this had been a window opened by acNormalWindow scroll bars would appear, but not when opened as a pop-up. What I need is either another way to halt execution or being able to force scroll bars on a window.

Comment: Can you provide any more information about your forms / general implementation?

Comment: I may have a sequence such as this: Present a form to the user where the items of interest can be marked, e.g, with a check box. When the form is closed the system will perform actions on the marked objects. Then it will be necessary to stop execution until the user has performed the action. This works fine on a large display, but on a laptop with a smaller display the forms are presented without a scroll-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Open it with acModal instead of acDialog

Comment: Hi, acModal is not an option for the windowmode attribute in OpenForm.

Comment: My bad.  Please open the form in design mode, in properties, others, select modal=yes, let me know if that works, I'll write another answer if needed.

Comment: Hi Manuel. You are absolutely right. Modal = yes should work, but it doesn't. As far as I can see the only way to stop execution is to open the form as acDialog. The problem with the scroll bars become apparent when one try to use an application over Remote Desktop, then pop-up/modal forms will not get scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, this works for me - making the forms Modal (and without opening them with WindowMode=acDialog)